# return true if there is no letters

Tags: java, regex

This method is one of several. I was wondering if I am correct in the line here that says "if(dig1.contains() && dig2.contains() && res.contains())". in the regex
1. I need to make sure that there is no letters in the string
2. I need to see if the sum of string1 and string2 add up to the third string. else return false. Thank you all for your help. This is so far what I have.

```
/**
  Returns true if the puzzle is solved.
  @return true if the puzzle has no letters and the 
  first two numbers add up to the third
*/
public boolean isSolved()
{
   String dig1=""+add1;
   String dig2=""+add2;
   String res=""+result;
   //String a1=""+dig1;
   if(dig1.contains("[^A-Z]") && dig2.contains("[^A-Z]") && res.contains("[^A-Z]")){
      int i=Integer.parseInt(dig1);
      int j=Integer.parseInt(dig2);
      int k=Integer.parseInt(res);

        if(i+j==k)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
     }
   else
       return false;
```

}

Comment: What if string contains other symbols, apart from digits and letters? You'll get NumberFormatException.

Comment: No, it is completely digits and letters. The input is something like this: add1=SJF3G add2=SDFH3 result=3SH4H. No symbols or anything else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One more thing. I noticed that you tend to do this: `String dig1 = "" + add1;`. If you want to concat strings, just do `String dig1 += add1;` or if you want to assign one string to another, do this `String dig1 = add1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use regular expressions for that? `Integer.parseInt()` will throw an exception if conversion is not possible. Just catch the exception and then you know that the strings contained something else than digits. Something along the line of this:

```
public boolean isSolved() {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(dig1);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(dig2);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(res);
        return (i+j) == k;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use another regex. IT will check if your strings contain only digits:

```
if (dig1.matches("^[0-9]*$")
    && dig2.matches("^[0-9]*$")
    && res.matches("^[0-9]*$"))
```

With your current code you will get exceptions in many cases, e.g. when there are small-cased letters.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. Strandjev. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a try-catch statement:

```
try {
    int i=Integer.parseInt(dig1);
    int j=Integer.parseInt(dig2);
    int k=Integer.parseInt(res);

    if(i+j==k)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException numForEx) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's a complicated way to convert a string to an integer. (if thats what you are asking)

```
public boolean isSolved()
{
   String dig1=""+add1;
   String dig2=""+add2;
   String res=""+result;
   try{
      int i=Integer.parseInt(dig1);
      int j=Integer.parseInt(dig2);
      int k=Integer.parseInt(res);

     if((i+j)==k) return true;
     return false;
   } catch {
     return false;
   }
}
```

So, basically, you could just wrap this in a try/catch-block, 
then you don't have to use the regular-expressions to check the strings beforehand.

I added my addtl comment here: if you are going to use this all over the place, refactor it into a method:

```
private boolean IsOnlyNumbers( String input ){ 
  try{ 
    Integer.parseInt(input); 
    return true; 
  } catch { 
    return false;
  }
}
```

or, since you need the number, you could do this:

```
private int GetNumber( String input ){ 
  try{ 
    return Integer.parseInt(input); 
  } catch { 
    return -1;
  }
}
```

and then check:

```
var dig1 = GetNumber(add1);
var dig2 = GetNumber(add2);
var res = GetNumber(add2);
if( dig1 > 0 && dig2 > 0 && dig3 > 0 ) return dig1+dig2 == res;
```

Comment: Thank you mindandmedia for your help. I appreciate your help.

Comment: you are very welcome. and since you are so polite, here another suggestion: make the whole thing into a function: private boolean containsNoLetters( String input ){ try{ Integer.parseInt(input); return true; } catch { return false }}); then you can reuse it...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this solution

```
public boolean isSolved() {
    try {
        int dig1 = Integer.parseInt(add1);
        int dig2 = Integer.parseInt(add2);
        int res = Integer.parseInt(result);

        return dig1 + dig2 == res;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In case all strings are numbers, the conversion is correct and than you can compare the numbers. In case on of the contains letters or other bad characters, an exception is thrown and `false` is returned.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Tomas for your help.